# Start activity for result from object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say you have an activity **A** that use an object **mObject** (e.g. here a client for an API).

This object constructor check whether or not the user is already identified, and if he's not, start a login form activity (**B**) that prompt user for credentials so that the API can just log him.

How can you do that?

I've thought just asking for the Context in the constructor but actually it doesn't implement *startActivityForResult* so I either have to cast it or to actually ask for a Activity object.

Even if I do this however, the result will be sent on the *onActivityResult* callback (of the activity A) and not in the object (while ideally, I would like to do it "synchronously" : when the activity is returned, store it in an object and continue the execution of the constructor).

What would be a good way to do this, then?

Comment: show some codes mate

Comment: I've not much at the moment, just an empty activity, another activity with 2 buttons and an object that wraps a Retrofit adapter.

Comment: use a fragment, fragments can access objects from the activity

Comment: So I should implement the API client object as a fragment?

Comment: nope, you share the same object between fragment and activity. The login will be done in a fragment on the object created will be updated. Doing it synchronously will block the ui.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I'll look this way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not reasonable to do that in a constructor.
It's also not a great idea to have a non-Activity class use the Activity's Context to start another activity.

The most straightforward way would be for Activity A to use mObject to determine whether login is required, and if so Activity A should start Activity B (startActivityForResult is fine if you need to pass data back to Activity A from Activity B).

How you communicate the login data to mObject is up to you, but you'll probably want mObject to be shared somehow between Activity A and Activity B.

There are a few ways to do that.
You could have mObject as a member of your Application class.
Or you could have mObject just be a class with static data and static methods.
Or you could use a dependency injection framework, and inject mObject into both activities.

Comment: Is it unreasonable to store credentials on persistent memory using SharedPreferences and load them everytime an instance is created (instead of using a singleton or application context or a DI) ? And also, should I check for the user input validity on the activity B and return these results once they are validated (display warning etc.) or return them, validate them on activity A and restart activity B if they are not valid?

Comment: re: credential storage - you should probably ask a separate question.

Your other questions - up to you. Try it and do what works best for you.